# Rotating two images on opposite directons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, rotation

I am completely new to javascript. Now I am trying to write a code to rotate two images in opposite directions. You can see the code [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/V5y6p/).

HTML:

```
<body>  
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <img class="leftwheel" src="http://exchangedownloads.smarttech.com/public/content/b3/b37268f0-9252-4c12-bb12-b5e68f582410/previews/medium/0001.png"/>
  <img class="rightwheel" src="http://exchangedownloads.smarttech.com/public/content/b3/b37268f0-9252-4c12-bb12-b5e68f582410/previews/medium/0001.png"/>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
body{
background:#fff;
}
body > img{
width:200px;
}
.leftwheel {
float:left;
}
.rightwheel {
    float:right;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {

    var $rotaLeft = $(' .leftwheel'),
    var $rotaRight = $(' .rightwheel'),
        degreeRight = 0,
        degreeLeft = 0,
        timerLeft,
        timerRight;

    function rotateLeft() {    
        $rotaLeft.css({ transform: 'rotate(' + degreeLeft + 'deg)'});
        // timeout increase degrees:
        timerLeft = setTimeout(function() {
            ++degreeLeft;
            rotateLeft(); // loop
        },25);
    }
    function rotateRight() {    
        $rotaRight.css({ transform: 'rotate(' + degreeRight + 'deg)'});
        // timeout increase degrees:
        timerRight = setTimeout(function() {
            --degreeRight;
            rotateRight(); // loop
        },25);
    }

    rotateRight();
    rotateLeft();    // run

});
```

But both the images are not rotating. But when I try to rotate one at a time using the following javascript:

```
$(function() {

    var $rotaLeft = $(' .leftwheel'),
        degreeLeft = 0,
        timerLeft;

    function rotateLeft() {    
        $rotaLeft.css({ transform: 'rotate(' + degreeLeft + 'deg)'});
        // timeout increase degrees:
        timerLeft = setTimeout(function() {
            ++degreeLeft;
            rotateLeft(); // loop it
        },25);
    }
    rotateLeft();    // run it!

});
```

It is working. What am I doing wrong when trying to rotate both?

Comment: are you not allowed to use CSS?

Comment: I am using CSS. I need infinite rotation That is why using javascript.

Comment: but you can use keyframe animation like this.. http://jsbin.com/nulepuki/1/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve the effect using `@keyframes animation`. here is the **[working example](http://jsbin.com/nulepuki/1/edit)**.

Here is a CSS code.

```
img{float:left;}
.leftwheel {
    -webkit-animation: rotation 2s infinite linear;
    animation: rotation 2s infinite linear;
  -moz-animation: rotation 2s infinite linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotation {
    from {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to   {-webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);}
}
@-moz-keyframes rotation {
    from {-moz-transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to   {-moz-transform: rotate(359deg);}
}
@keyframes rotation {
    from {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to   {transform: rotate(359deg);}
}

.rightwheel {
    -webkit-animation: rotation1 2s infinite linear;
    animation: rotation1 2s infinite linear;
  -moz-animation: rotation1 2s infinite linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotation1 {
    from {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to   {-webkit-transform: rotate(-359deg);}
}
@-moz-keyframes rotation1 {
    from {-moz-transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to   {-moz-transform: rotate(-359deg);}
}
@keyframes rotation1 {
    from {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to   {transform: rotate(-359deg);}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have declared below variable in wrong way

```
var $rotaLeft = $(' .leftwheel'),
var $rotaRight = $(' .rightwheel'),
```

It should be like

```
var $rotaLeft = $(' .leftwheel'); // put semicolon instead of comma
var $rotaRight = $(' .rightwheel'),
```

or

```
var $rotaLeft = $(' .leftwheel'),
    $rotaRight = $(' .rightwheel'), // remove var keyword
```

Rest all your code is working fine :)

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/V5y6p/5/)**

Comment: Thanks. That solved the issue. I am not that familiar with this kind of variable declaration. :)

Comment: Kheema Pandey's answer solved it in a better way. Anyway this tip was really handy. :)

Answer (score 0):

Comma seperated values should come under one var declarations. Declare your variable like this way.

```
    var $rotaLeft = $(' .leftwheel'),
    degreeLeft = 0,
    timerLeft;

    var $rotaRight = $(' .rightwheel'),
    degreeRight = 0,       
    timerRight;
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/PD86f/)